# What version / flavour of Python is used in Appengine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I just wondered for the second time which version of Python is used for the
Google Appengine Python 2.7 runtime.

This is absolutely valid Python since 2.6 and I expect query_string to be "test" afterwards:

```
query_string = "(test)"
query_string = query_string.translate(None, "()")
```

But on Google Appengine, it leads to a TypeError *translate() takes exactly one argument (2 given)*

Last week, we were experiencing another strange behaviour, a function a called another function b which might raise a ValueError. I could catch the exception inside function b, but not in a, the backend just crashed because of a propagation of the exception.
Some hours later though, this bug(?) was fixed.

EDIT: I'm using the Python 2.7 runtime and `sys.version` returns `2.7.3 (default, Oct 15 2012, 11:27:13)`

app.yaml:

```
application: test
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: no
```

Answer (score 5):

Edit based on your update:
This may or may not be the root-cause of the issue, but your `app.yaml` is incorrect. The allowed value for `threadsafe` is either `true` or `false`. Link to appropriate section of the documentation: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig

---

Original answer:
The only way this could be happening is if you are not specifying that GAE should use the Python 2.7 runtime for your app in `app.yaml`. Below is [an example from the excellent documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/helloworld):

```
application: helloworld
version: 1
#        vvvvvvvv
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: helloworld.app
```

If you don't specify `python27` for the `runtime` GAE will use Python 2.5

Comment: Yes, I'm using the Python 2.7 runtime, I just added that information to the question.

Answer (score 2):

It's a little bit embarassing, GAE is behaviour is absolutely normal,
the string I used was a unicode object, not a str.

Comment: FWIW, this is the second time this has bit me, and the first time I understood why.  Thanks :)